# parent max-height not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My HTML code has a div with a class `parent` and it has `60%` max-height.
Inside this div has an image with `max-height: 100%`
The concept is that: the image should be 100% height inside the parent div.
**index.html**

```
<div class="parent">
<img src="https://gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net/806614/photos/photos.500px.net/86054889/a33fe4cc9c14a08fdf785e82c400b254caa4aed4/5.jpg?v=5" alt="" />
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    background: green;
}
html, body {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0px;
}
.parent {
    max-height: 60% !important;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: #444;
    text-align: center;
}
.parent img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

The image listen its parent div height perfectly in chrome but in firefox the image is not listening the parent div height rather it achieves its own heights.
How can i make it work on firefox?

**CodePen Link**: Here the code on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/rakib/pen/imjaC), what i have tried so far.

Comment: it produce similar effect in Chrome as well as Firefox.. Please check your code once again

Comment: Set `height: 100%;` on `.parent` and `.parent img`.